# Sunspot/Solr: indexing a time field results in NumberFormatException

Tags: ruby, solr, lucene, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I'm trying to add a timestamp field to my model for indexing by Sunspot/Solr. Solr chokes on this and produces a `NumberFormatException`:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lastUpdated, :category, :title  # etc...

  searchable do
    text :title
    text :category
    time :lastUpdated   # mysql 'datetime' field
    # etc...
  end
end

Jun 06, 2012 10:59:10 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2012-01-02T03:29:00Z"
```

I've also tried using `date :lastUpdated` with the same results.

Thinking that perhaps my model has some bogus `lastUpdated` values, I tried indexing the results from `Time.now`, and got the same results.

I'm using Solr 3.4.0 externally, but have reproduced the same problem using the "internal" Solr provided by `sunspot-installer`, and adjusting `sunspot.yml` accordingly. My situation seems a lot like the problem mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ruby-sunspot/c7GluD8jsHk), but re-installing the Sunspot/Solr config does not seem to fix it.

**Edit**: have also tried against Solr 3.6.0; same result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that this is due to a bug in Sunspot's type.rb. `TimeType` defines its `indexed_name`to be "_d", rather than "_dt". I've worked around this in my model code with the following:

```
module Sunspot
  module Type
    class TimeType < AbstractType
      def indexed_name(name) #:nodoc:
        "#{name}_dt"
      end
    end
    register TimeType
  end
end
```

Comment: After 3 years, this answer is still relevant and the bug is still present. I opened a issue on Github for this.

Comment: Fix worked for me too, almost 5 years later!  Placed this override this at the top of my model, before the class definition.  Using Solr 6.0.1 / Sunspot 2.2.7

Comment: Another year pass and we are still facing the same issue, your fix is still valid but why this code does not work from config/initializer/sunspot/type.rb file.

Comment: As of June 2019, still very relevant. Thank you!

Comment: It is 2022 and solution is still working.

Comment: 2024 and this is still relevant... Thanks again!